# SQL Command not properly ended trying to join 3 tables using query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-apex

Hello I am trying to add a Translated_Name column from the Product_descriptions table to my current query that is already joining two tables however the translated_name column is a type NVARCHAR2. Should I be using Inner Join for it or am I completely wrong?

```
select order_mode,customer_id,product_id from ORDERS
       inner join ORDER_items on order_items.ORDER_ID=Orders.ORDER_ID
where exists(select customer_id from customers where orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id)
       inner join product_descriptions on product_descriptions.translated_name = Orders.Customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The `where` clause goes after the `join`s:

```
select  
    order_mode,
    customer_id,
    product_id 
from orders o
inner join order_items oi 
    on oi.order_id = o.order_id
inner join product_descriptions pd 
    on pd.translated_name = o.customer_id
where exists(
    select 1
    from customers c 
    where o.customer_id = c.customer_id
)
```

Notes:

- table aliases make the query easier to read and write
- you should qualify the columns the the `from` clause with the alias of the table they belong to
- I am quite suspicious about the join condition on `product_descriptions`, which involves `customer_id`; you might need to review that (without knowing your table structures, it is not possible to tell what the correct condition is)